# How to subscript a letter or numeric digit in text of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want y-axis labelled as: Serum Levels of Thyroxine (T4) with 4 in T4 as subscripted. In my code, I tried labs(y = expression(Serum Levels of Thyroxine ([T4]). However it did not work. Previous questions have only adrressed the letters to be subscripted, however, problem arises when the letter or no. to be subscripted is after some words/ text.
My data frame and code is below

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("1 h","6 h","12 h","24 h","3 days"),
    values = c(1,2,3,4,5))
  df %>% 
      ggplot(aes(time,values))+
      geom_point()+
      labs(y = "Serum Thyroxine T4 levels", 
    x = "Exposure Period")
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I edited the question

Comment: ggplot(df, aes(time,values))+ geom_point()+ labs(x = expression(Exposure~Period) , y = expression(Serum~Thyroxine~T["4"]~levels~(ng/ml)))

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is due to the spaces used within the expression. The way to get around this is to replace each space with `~`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(time = c("1 h","6 h","12 h","24 h","3 days"),
                 values = c(1,2,3,4,5))
ggplot(df, aes(time,values)) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(y = expression(Serum~Thyroxine~T[4]~levels~(ng/ml)), x = "Exposure Period")
```

*EDIT: Moved T out of []*

Comment: When I use your code,  get this error: Error: unexpected '[' in:
"  geom_point() + 
  labs(y = expression(Serum~Thyroxine~["
>

Comment: This works: labs(y = expression(Serum~Thyroxine~T[4]~levels~(ng/ml)), x = "Exposure Period")

Comment: Thanks, miscopied it over from my local session

Comment: Thank you very much